# Adding more fields to the signup form

Tags: python, django

I want to know if I can add more fields to the signup form if a user checks a box. For example, if the user checks the box that says he is a photographer one more field will appear in which he can specify what type of photography he does.

Comment: What you have been tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what DHTML is. You need to add an event on the checkbox which will dynamically add the INPUT element in the form. something like.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="addInput(this)" id="photography">
```

now in the method add a text element dynamically with dynamic id e.g.(value-photography) so that you can take an action on server side.

you need to make use of

```
document.appendChild()
```

You can use jQuery as well.